Designing a Simple Custom Encryption Algorithm for Messaging: Introducing the "MessageMix Cipher"
I'm working on developing a custom encryption algorithm specifically tailored for messaging applications. The goal is to balance security, efficiency, and simplicity, so that the algorithm is lightweight enough for real-time communication but still provides a reasonable level of security. I’ve come up with an outline for a simple encryption algorithm, which I’m calling the "MessageMix Cipher." I would appreciate feedback on the approach and any suggestions for improvements.
MessageMix Cipher

Key Generation

User Input: The user provides a passphrase to derive a key.
Hashing: The passphrase is hashed using a cryptographic hash function (e.g., SHA-256) to produce a fixed-length key.
Key Length: The key can be 128 or 256 bits based on the required security level.

Message Preprocessing

Padding: If the message length isn’t a multiple of 16 bytes, pad the message (e.g., PKCS#7).
Chunking: Break the message into 128-bit blocks.

Encryption Process

Initial Vector (IV): Generate a random 128-bit IV for each message.
Step 1: Key Expansion
Expand the hashed key using a scheduling algorithm to create multiple round keys.
Step 2: Mixing Function
For each block, perform:
Substitution: Replace each byte using an S-box derived from the hash of the key.
Permutation: Rearrange the bytes within the block.
XOR with Round Key: XOR the block with a round key.
Mix Columns (optional): Mix bytes across columns for added diffusion.
Step 3: Ciphertext Generation
Concatenate the encrypted blocks and prepend the IV.

Decryption Process

IV Extraction: Extract the IV from the ciphertext.
Reverse Mixing Function: Reverse the encryption steps for each block.
Combine Blocks: Reassemble the decrypted blocks.
Remove Padding: Recover the original message by removing padding.

Security Considerations

Key Strength: Ensure the passphrase is strong to prevent brute-force attacks.
IV Usage: Use a unique IV for each message.
Hash Function: The security relies on the hash function’s strength.
Advantages of MessageMix Cipher
Simplicity: Easy to implement with minimal computational overhead.
Security: Provides a reasonable level of security for messaging.
Efficiency: Suitable for real-time messaging.
Limitations
Not as strong as AES: While secure for most messaging, it’s not as rigorously tested as AES.
Key Management: Users must manage their passphrase securely.
My Questions:
Are there any potential vulnerabilities in this design that I should be aware of?
How might I improve the algorithm’s security without compromising its simplicity?
Would this algorithm be suitable for real-time messaging in a typical app, or should I consider additional measures?
Looking forward to your insights!

Before creating you own algorithm, I would really check if you need to - I strongly expect that AES (using an appropriate library) will be more than fast enough

AES is in hardware on most CPU's and will blow the socks off of this (especially with the Zen 5, but that's another topic). As a further hint, you'll need a Password Based Key Derivation Function rather than a hash, and the password needs to be pretty strong to disallow brute force / dictionary attacks. It seems you are describing a general block cipher in #3, but in that case it is operating in ECB mode which is obviously not secure. We try and avoid padding nowadays as padding oracles are a real threat.
